# Android Progress bars losing their value when updated in a Handler

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android app that displays cell phone usage information in a progress bar.  The bar changes color based on the amount of usage from green to yellow to red.  When my TimerTask executes the update though (via a Handler so it goes through the UI thread and not the Timer thread), the progress bars empty, even though the text labels are updated correctly.  The code updating the progress bar is:

```
private void SetBarColor(ProgressBar bar, int progress, int secondaryAdditive){
    int setTo = R.drawable.greenbar;

    if(progress < 60)
        setTo = R.drawable.greenbar;
    else if (progress < 90)
        setTo = R.drawable.yellowbar;
    else
        setTo = setTo = R.drawable.redbar;

    bar.setProgress(progress);
    bar.setSecondaryProgress(progress + secondaryAdditive); //Mocking up phone usage

    Rect bounds = bar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
    bar.setProgressDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(setTo));
    bar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

This method works fine when called the first time in the onCreate method, but when called from the TimerTask, the bars simply hide themselves, showing only the grey background (as if their progress == 0).  I've used the debugger and confirmed that the right values are going into the setProgress and setSecondaryProgress() calls.  I have also tried setting the progress both before (as in the snippet above) and after the setProgressDrawable call, to no avail.

Anyone run into something like this?

EDIT:  By request, some additional code.  Here's the Runnable:

```
private class MyTime extends TimerTask {         
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ReQueryCount--;
        if(ReQueryCount <= 0){
            ReQueryCount = ReQueryCountStarter;

            HeartbeatHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    GetDataFromServer();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

The HeartbeatHandler is created in onCreate.

GetDataFromServer gets some data from server, but the part that consumes my SetBarColor above is:

```
private void UpdateProgressBars(ServiceHelper.UsageResult result) {

    int voiceBarProg = (int)((double)result.VoiceUsage / (double)result.MaxVoice * 100);
    int dataBarProg = (int)((double)result.DataUsage / (double)result.MaxData * 100);
    int msgBarProg = (int)((double)result.TextUsage / (double)result.MaxText * 100);

    SetBarColor(voiceBar, voiceBarProg, PhoneVoice);
    SetBarColor(dataBar, dataBarProg, PhoneData);
    SetBarColor(msgBar, msgBarProg, PhoneText);
}
```

Short of posting the layouts, manifest and the rest I'm not sure what other code would be helpful.

Comment: Probably add some more code, the more the better. Also, you are calling the above via a runnable?

Comment: I am calling the above via a Runnable.  It's not a cross-thread problem as far as I can tell (I had a WrongThread exception earlier, but resolved it by using a Runnable).

Comment: Well you might want to put enough code up so we can see the setup etc. maybe even compile something.  I don't see anything wrong from a glance at what you posted, maybe someone else will, although not sure why you need to set visible every update, realize you are probably just trying to resolve

Comment: I updated to include the TimerTask that is firing off the Runnable and the method which actually consumes SetBarColor.  I'm pretty new to Android development (and Java for that matter) so I'm not really sure what else might help :/

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours for a solution of this problem I have found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953534/1967189) that has an answer that has helped me.

But in addition to the answer there I have also get/set the drawable bounds too. So I have a custom ProgressBar which has the following method to set progress color and amount:

```
    public void setProgressColorAndFill(int color, int fill){
    Drawable bgDrawable = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{0xFFdadada, 0xFFdadada});
    Drawable proDrawable = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{color, color});
    ClipDrawable clip = new ClipDrawable(proDrawable, Gravity.LEFT,ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);

    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
    layers[0] = bgDrawable;
    layers[1] = clip;

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
    layerDrawable.setId(0, android.R.id.background);
    layerDrawable.setId(1, android.R.id.progress);

    Rect bounds = ((LayerDrawable)getProgressDrawable()).getBounds();
    setProgressDrawable(layerDrawable);
    getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);

    setProgress(1);
    setMax(100);
    setProgress(fill);
}
```

Hope this will be useful to someone.